# tkprof options to get input parameters of a stored procedure

Tags: oracle, parameter-passing, trace

I have an Oracle trace ouptut, I use `tkprof inputtracefilename.trc output.prf` to get the readable format.  However, I want to see what the values are passed to a procedure.

I got the following text in the output.prf:

```
Begin ebp_set_char_data(:v0, :v1, :v2, :v3, :v4, :v5, :v6); End;
```

I want to know what v0...v6 input values are.  What options do I use to get the information?

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the trace with level 4 at least ie:

```
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET EVENTS '10046 trace name context forever, level 4';
```

Then run your api calls

Finally to turn off tracing :

```
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET EVENTS '10046 trace name context off';
```

Note level 4 =bind info, level 8 =wait info and level 12 = both wait and bind info

Then check the raw trace file for the bind info